# Javascript object of arrays undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following function:

```
function get_stoplight_color(count, position) {
    console.log(count + ', ' + position);

    var colors = {
        'QB' : ['#8b3a25', '#ceca63', '#68c24c', '#68c24c', '#68c24c'],
        'RB' : ['#8b3a25', '#ceca63', '#ceca63', '#ceca63', '#68c24c'],
        'WR' : ['#8b3a25', '#ceca63', '#ceca63', '#ceca63', '#ceca63'],
        'TE' : ['#8b3a25', '#ceca63', '#68c24c', '#68c24c', '#68c24c'],
        'DST' : ['#8b3a25', '#68c24c', '#68c24c', '#68c24c', '#68c24c'],
        'K' : ['#8b3a25', '#68c24c', '#68c24c', '#68c24c', '#68c24c']
    };

    console.log(colors);
    if (count <= 4) return colors.position[count];
    else return '#68c24c';
}
```

As you can see, I've logged a couple vars out to the console, and they appear to be just fine there. However, at runtime I'm getting the following error:

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined***

(That's when `count` = 4.)

Again, the object `colors` clearly exists, because `console.log(colors)` outputs:

```
Object {QB: Array[5], RB: Array[5], WR: Array[5], TE: Array[5], DST: Array[5]…}
```

So I would expect `colors.position[count]` to return `#68c24c` when `position` = 'QB' and `count` = 4.

Why is the object still returning `undefined` in this case? Thank you, and I'll provide more details if necessary (I've provided everything I've thought of up front).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `colors.position[count]` uses a **`position`** property on `colors`. I think you meant `colors[position][count]`, which will look up the property named by the variable `position` (e.g., `QB`) on `colors` instead, and then look up the property named by `count` (e.g., `4`) on the result.

If there's any chance `position` may not be defined, I would change that bit at the end slightly. Instead of:

```
if (count <= 4) return colors.position[count];
else return '#68c24c';
```

perhaps:

```
return (colors[position] && colors[position][count]) || '#68c24c';
```

...which takes advantage of JavaScript's [curiously-powerful `||` and `&&` operators](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html).

---

Re your comment below:

> Wow, OK, that worked, but I'm not sure how? I didn't even try that since I view [] operands as indexes of an array, while colors is an object (not an array).

In JavaScript (unlike many languages), you can access an object property in two ways:

1. Using dot notation and a literal property name, e.g. `obj.foo` (provided the property name is a valid [*identifier name*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6)), or
2. Using bracketed notation and a *string* property name, e.g. `obj["foo"]` (and in this case, the property name can be just about anything, it doesn't have to be a valid identifier name).

In the second case, the string can be from any expression, including a variable lookup. So all of these refer to `obj.foo`:

```
obj.foo
obj["foo"]
obj["f" + "o" + "o"]
var x = "o";
obj["f" + x + x]
```

...and in fact, this is is the **same** notation you use when dealing with arrays, because in JavaScript, [arrays aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), they're just objects.

Comment: Wow, OK, that worked, but I'm not sure how? I didn't even try that since I view `[]` operands as indexes of an array, while `colors` is an object (not an array). Guess I have more to learn about objects. Thanks!

Comment: @praguian: Ah, no, in JavaScript `[]` is more powerful than that. :-) I've updated the answer to explain that a bit more. `[]` is very useful with objects (and arrays are just objects).

Comment: Thanks! Very informative and helpful. I wish I could upvote your answer more than once.

Answer (score 4):

If position is a variable then you should say `colors[position][count]`. Otherwise JS will think `position` is a property of `colors` and not resolve its value.